# All ways of JVM to JVM communication

Tags: java, jvm, communication

I want a list of all the ways two JVMs can communicate. The JVMs can be local or remote.

The obvious ones are

- Socket Communication
- RMI
- Shared Memory(File/Database)

Note: I am not interested in comparing these as the way we choose depends on the need. I am curious to know what all ways actually exist.

Comment: A fairly generic question. 2 JVMs can interact using "any" existing protocol, e.g. 2 JVMs can interact based on JSON. Maybe should should further describe what you mean by _communicate_?

Comment: The reality is that anything that can be manipulated in one process and read in another is a possible means of IPC.

Comment: For a more bizarre example, one could communicate with the other by taking a screenshot of a monitor and processing it!

Comment: @home Agree. I feel stupid now, but I'm glad I got to know that this is not the right question to ask. I will read up about IPC more and see how I can do it in Java.
By communicate I just meant that I should be able to send a signal/message/have the ability to change some state in the other JVM.

Comment: @Jeff To me that falls under 'File I/O' as we use a file for the communication.

Comment: @Sundeep no, you use an embedded javacard with probes into a pigeon's visual cortex to process the screenshot embroidered on a silk scarf by a java controlled robot.

Comment: Don't forget [IPoAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers).  I heard a test was done, and it proved to offer a higher data rate than one of the  major ISPs of South Africa.

Comment: @Pete  Now that is **two** techniques employing the power of pigeons.  Those birds are running hot, tonight.

Comment: @Pete That's Funny. There's no second JVM by way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Simple and sure shot answer! What I was looking for is on Wikipedia!

Comment: @Sundeep that is the definition of a poor question.  If a simple google search turns it up, it is not a good candidate

Comment: @Woot4Moo True. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know it without the help of another human!